# Manipulating video timestamps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I do math using video timestamps of the format "00:01:00"?

For example, given a timestamp like, `var start = "00:01:00";`, how can I add time to `start` using another timestamp (e.g. `var end = "00:05:00"`) and come away with a result using that same format (e.g. `var sum = "00:06:00"`)?

I have looked into using Moment.js to do this, but that library wants to coerce everything to a Date, which doesn't seem like a good fit for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can do that with moment, check below code.

```js
var date = moment("00:01:00", 'mm:ss:SS');

var date2 = moment("00:05:00", 'mm:ss:SS');

date.add(date2);

var element = document.getElementById('app');

element.innerHTML = date.format('mm:ss:SS');
```

```html
<div id="app"> </app>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Though, I just not realized I didn't convey the trickiest part of my problem. I need to add that offset using another video style timestamp. I will update my question now.

Comment: Interestingly, your answer works with Moment 2.2.1, however 2.24.0 (latest) fails with this error: "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info." This is part of the reason why I was concerned about using `Date`. Seeing as your solution does work, I'll gladly give you the credit. Thanks!